# UI.X Xenforo Theme AD Styler

Tags: xenforo

On my Xenforo Audentio UI.X theme, there is an AD Styler at the bottom, allowing me to customize the background. If I disable the AD Styler, the background turns white. How can I keep the background image without having the AD Styler showing at the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 3):

Appearance > Styles > UI.X >  Style Property Groups > Generals > Body In background section put image for your background